# Cluster variables together and run ANOVA

Tags: r, grouping, anova

I want to cluster 16 continuous (7-point Likert Scale) variables into three separate categories, and then use a factor to run an ANOVA against it. Currently, I'm having problems with clustering the variables together so it can be run as an ANOVA.
This is what I have so far.

```
> class(test)
data.frame
> colnames(test)
[1] "S1"   "S2"   "S3"   "S4"   "S5"   "S6"   "S7"   "S8"  
[9] "S9"   "S10"  "S11"  "S12"  "S13"  "S14"  "S15" "S16" 
[17] "Condition"
> lapply(test[,1:16], class)
numeric
> class(test$Condition)
factor
```

How do I cluster variables together - say, S1-5, S6-10, S11-16 - and use the factor test$Condition as the independent variable?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on what are the sorts of data that are in those columns? Saying they are "continuous" is not particularly helpful. Do you just want to give them equal weights and add them up?

Comment: @BondedDust, I've considered giving them weights, but I would end up losing information in doing so. I was hoping if anyone has an idea with grouping variables into clusters.

Comment: So you don't know what you are doing and want statistical advice? That's off-topic on SO.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: (1) This is more of a statistics question than an R question, so you might be better off on http://stats.stackexchange.com/. (2) In R, you might want to check out the [`survey`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) and [`likert`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/likert/index.html) packages. Read the vignettes. (3) If you post your actual data, or a link to it, you are more likely to get a response here.

Comment: @BondedDust, I think that's the reason why I'm on this forum: to elicit ideas from others. I have an idea how it works theoretically, mind you. I'm simply a R novice, much like how you were when you first started. Still, thank you for your contribution. Nice profile background, though it contradicts my initial presumptions based on your comments.

Comment: @jlhoward, thanks for this suggestion. I've started looking into it!

Comment: If you put the data in long format, you can add another variable that designates where the observation came from.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, sorry for the late response, and I figured something out already. Still, thank you! :)

Comment: Consider answering your own question for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code on me, but originally I was aiming for a sophisticated method to cluster variables together with minimal errors. Instead, I opted for two methods when combining the variables: 1) averaging the groups; 2) summing up the groups. One should note, however, that the selected method has an impact on the output (i.e., beta weights, marginal means, etc.) - p-values remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
# this function give you the number of clusters as variable n in R #        #  programming test your datastes.
    clusrer.data <- function(test,n) {
      data <- t(test)
     z <- rbind(data)
      (cl <- kmeans(z, n))
cl

 }
```

## recall function

```
 clusrer.data(test, 3)# give you 3 clusters each cluster have 5 features.
```

## then i think you can use one way  ANOVA with 3 clusters, as a result from the # k-means.